# Combining tailwind css with sass using webpack

Tags: css, webpack, sass, tailwind-css

I'm struggling a bit getting Tailwind CSS to work with SASS and Webpack. It seems like the postcss configuration for tailwind doesn't really do anything in terms of processing `@tailwind preflight`, `@tailwind components` and `@tailwind utilities`

My set up is as follows:

**layout.scss**

```
@import "~tailwindcss/preflight.css";
@import "~tailwindcss/components.css";

.my-class {
    @apply text-blue;    
    @apply border-red;
}

@import "~tailwindcss/utilities.css";
```

**entry.js**

```
import '../css/src/layout.scss';
```

**postcss.config.js**

```
const tailwindcss = require('tailwindcss');
const purgecss = require('@fullhuman/postcss-purgecss');
const cssnano = require('cssnano');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        tailwindcss('./tailwind.js'),
        cssnano({
            preset: 'default',
        }),
        purgecss({
            content: ['./views/**/*.cshtml']
        }),
        autoprefixer
    ]
 }
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
// NPM plugins
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const WebpackNotifierPlugin = require('webpack-notifier');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require("optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin");
const BrowserSyncPlugin = require('browser-sync-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        main: './scripts/entry.js'
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        publicPath: './'
    },
    watch: false,
    externals: {
        jquery: 'jQuery'
    },
    mode: 'development',
    plugins: [
        // Notify when build succeeds
        new WebpackNotifierPlugin({ alwaysNotify: true }),

        // Extract any CSS from any javascript file to process it as LESS/SASS using a loader
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            fileame: "[name].bundle.css"
        }),

        // Minify CSS assets
        new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({}),

        // Use BrowserSync plugin for file changes. I.e. if a CSS/SASS/LESS file changes, the changes will be injected directly in the browser with no page load
        new BrowserSyncPlugin({
            proxy: 'mysite.local',
            open: 'external',
            host: 'mysite.local',
            port: 3000,
            files: ['./dist/main.css', './views', './tailwind.js']
        },
            {
                // disable reload from the webpack plugin since browser-sync will handle CSS injections and JS reloads
                reload: false
            })
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                // Transpile ES6 scripts for browser support
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
                    }
                }
            },            
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg|eot|ttf|woff)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader'
                    }
                ]
            },       
            {
                // Extract any SCSS content and minimize
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [                    
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    { loader: 'css-loader' },
                    {
                        loader: 'postcss-loader',
                        options: {
                            plugins: () => [autoprefixer()]
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'sass-loader',
                        options: {                            
                            plugins: () => [autoprefixer()]
                        }
                    } 
                ]
            },
            {
                // Extract any CSS content and minimize
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    { loader: 'css-loader', options: { importLoaders: 1 } },
                    { loader: 'postcss-loader' }
                ]
            }            
        ]
    }
};
```

When I run Webpack, everything runs just fine, but the content of `/dist/main.css` is:

`@tailwind preflight;@tailwind components;@tailwind utilities;.my-class{@apply text-blue;@apply border-red}`

I suspect it's related to the (order of) loaders, but I can't seem to figure out why it's not getting processed correctly.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here? :-)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12):

Wow, so after fiddling around with the loaders even more, I made it work :-) For future reference:

I added `options: { importLoaders: 1 }` to the css-loader for SCSS files and removed: `plugins: () => [autoprefixer()]` from the postcss-loader in my webpack.config.js file.

Full, updated webpack.config.js file:

```
// NPM plugins
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const WebpackNotifierPlugin = require('webpack-notifier');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require("optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin");
const BrowserSyncPlugin = require('browser-sync-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        main: './scripts/entry.js'
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        publicPath: './'
    },
    watch: false,
    externals: {
        jquery: 'jQuery'
    },
    mode: 'development',
    plugins: [
        // Notify when build succeeds
        new WebpackNotifierPlugin({ alwaysNotify: true }),

        // Extract any CSS from any javascript file to process it as LESS/SASS using a loader
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            fileame: "[name].bundle.css"
        }),

        // Minify CSS assets
        new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({}),

        // Use BrowserSync plugin for file changes. I.e. if a CSS/SASS/LESS file changes, the changes will be injected directly in the browser with no page load
        new BrowserSyncPlugin({
            proxy: 'mysite.local',
            open: 'external',
            host: 'mysite.local',
            port: 3000,
            files: ['./dist/main.css', './views', './tailwind.js']
        },
            {
                // disable reload from the webpack plugin since browser-sync will handle CSS injections and JS reloads
                reload: false
            })
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                // Transpile ES6 scripts for browser support
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
                    }
                }
            },            
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg|eot|ttf|woff)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader'
                    }
                ]
            },       
            {
                // Extract any SCSS content and minimize
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [                       
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    { loader: 'css-loader', options: { importLoaders: 1 } },                    
                    {
                        loader: 'postcss-loader'                        
                    },                    
                    {
                        loader: 'sass-loader',
                        options: {                            
                            plugins: () => [autoprefixer()]
                        }
                    }                    
                ]
            },
            {
                // Extract any CSS content and minimize
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    { loader: 'css-loader', options: { importLoaders: 1 } },
                    { loader: 'postcss-loader' }
                ]
            }            
        ]
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for following up on your own question, this was hugely helpful!

Answer (score -2):

There is an extension called tailwindcss-transpiler which compiles your layout.tailwind.scss files into pure CSS files.It also optimizing features.I hope it will be useful.

For VS Code
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sudoaugustin.tailwindcss-transpiler

For Atom
https://atom.io/packages/tailwindcss-transpiler